# How to filter select values using foreign keys in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have this app where I can upload a file to a specific category or subcategory. It works fine but the problem I'm having is when I'm trying to display select values only for a specific user and for a specific parent category it just shows me all the values stored in the database.

views.py

```
class AddDocumentView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'docman/forms/add-document.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('docman:index')
    success_message = 'Document was successfully added'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = self.request.user
        return super(AddDocumentView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ('user',)
        fields = [
            'file',
            'slug',
            'category',
        ]

    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(FileUploadForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, parent_id=None)
```

I've tried the solutions to the similar questions which is how I even got this far, but it's still not filtering by the user and I can't figure out how to get it to filter by the parent id either. Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, and I can provide more information if needed.

**-----------------SOLUTION UPDATE-----------------**

Thanks @solarissmoke I was able to get the user information to the form. Then I just did the same thing to capture the parent_id from the url using kwargs.

views.py

```
#  Override the view's get_form_kwargs method to pass the user and/or pk to the form:
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    kwargs = super(AddDocumentView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    #  Check if category exists with pk, otherwise none
    if Category.objects.filter(parent_id=pk):
        kwargs['pk'] = pk
    else:
        kwargs['pk'] = None
    return kwargs
```

Then I added the extra agument(pk) to **init**

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, user=None, pk=None, **kwargs):
    super(FileUploadForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if user:
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=user, parent_id=pk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is expecting a `user` argument, but you aren't supplying one, so `user` is always `None`. You can override the view's [`get_form_kwargs` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) to pass the user to the form:

```
class AddDocumentView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AddDocumentView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Your `FileUploadForm` will now get the user object and will filter results accordingly.

Comment: That worked well, Thanks. Would I go about passing the parent_id in the same way?

Comment: I don't know what `parent_id` is? If it is something that your view knows about, then yes.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. The parent_id was the primary key in the URL, so I used" kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk'] and modify __init__ to accept it as an argument. I'll post the updated solution soon.